# Why doesn't ListView.setAdapter(null) throw a null pointer exception?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, android-adapter

By chance I stumbled on this unique find. My code broke because I was getting a `NullPointerException` on my Adapter after implementing a LoaderManager when I didn't have the exception previously.

So, I took the debugger and stepped through my onCreate method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);

    // Irrelevant code removed

    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(mAccountAdapter);
    return mDrawerListView;
}
```

The irrelevant code just include adding a footer view and setting onClickListeners but not once in this method (or any other) do I assign something to `mAccountAdapter`. I know I'm supposed to, and I am going to, but I made the mistake of forgetting to do so.

When I use the debugger and set a breakpoint at the `setAdapter(mAccountAdapter)` line I can see that `mAccountAdapter` is null. However, I can step over it and move on without ever getting a null pointer exception. Why am I allowed to pass a null value into that function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why am I allowed to pass a null value into that function?

Why wouldn't you be? After all, the `ListView` starts with a `null` adapter when you first create it. If you look at [the source for `ListView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java) and its ancestors, they have lots of checks for if `mAdapter` (the data member that will hold the now-current `Adapter`) is `null`.

Comment: I did step through some of that but didn't understand everything. Perhaps I should take some time and go a little slower. I had no idea it started with a null adapter, and knowing that, this makes more sense.